# how to customize url validation using validation plugin

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery validation plugin URL validation for url validation. I ve added url:true to validate all valid URLs. The Validation plugin is great with the default functions it offers.

It accepts the urls started with www.

```
 $( "#myform" ).validate({
      rules: {
        field: {
          required: true,
          url: true
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of **[`addMethod`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod)** of `jquery-validation` and write your custom validation for `url`. Consider below example.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("validateURL", function(value, element) {
    //logic to validate your url as per your requirement
    //return bool value i.e. true or false
}, "* Invalid URL");
```

You can make use of it as below:

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
    rules: {
       field: {
          required: true,
          validateURL: true //call this
       }
    }
})
```